# Does placing a symbolic link in the path work the same as creating a symbolic link of an executable in the path?

Tags: command-line, executable, .profile

As the title says, I'm about to do an install of an executable. Normally I would either

1. install the executable to somewhere in my path, e.g. `$HOME/bin/`
2. add the directory to the path in `~/.profile` (if option 1 wasn't feasible)

However, instead of option 2, could I simply create a symbolic link to somewhere in my path?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a symlink of any path will be treated by the system as a directory. So if you have an application path like `/usr/share/myapp/myapp.bin` and you link `/usr/share/myapp` into `$HOME/bin`, the path to be called would be `$HOME/bin/myapp/myapp.bin` and you would still have to have `$HOME/bin/myapp` in your `$PATH`.

Linking the executable itself could work, but if `myapp.bin` evaluates its own pathname, that could cause problems too. I would instead create a starter script in your bin like this:

`$HOME/bin/myapp.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATHTOMYAPP=/usr/share/myapp
$PATHTOMYAPP/myapp.bin "$@"
```

Add execute permissions to myapp.sh, and now you can call `myapp.sh` to start `myapp.bin`